# My .onclick function for a child list only display for a split second - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I'd like to make a list that's nested within a list collapse on click, a sub-menu for a department. Real flashy like.

I'm using the .click function having hid all the sub-menus, but it is only showing for a slight second. I'm a super novice and began using Jquery last week. Here is my code:

Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $("ul.sitback").hide();
    });




$(function() {
    $("li.dept").click(function(){
    $("ul.sitback").toggle();
     });
     });
```

HTML:

```
<h3 align="center">Departments</h3>
<ul>
    <a href><li class="dept1">+ Take Care Products</li></a>
            <ul id="area1" class="sitback">
            <a href><li>Men's Products</li></a>
            <a href><li>Women's Products</li></a>
            </ul>
    <a href><li class="dept">+ Home Electronics</li></a>
            <ul id="area" class="sitback">
            <a href><li>Televisions</li></a>
            <a href><li>Audio</li></a>
            <a href><li>Portable</li></a>
            </ul>
    <a href><li class="dept">+ Computers and Video Games</li></a>
            <ul  id="area" class="sitback">
            <a href><li>Video Games</li></a>
            <a href><li>Home Computers</li></a>
            </ul>
    <a href><li class="dept" data-department="dept4">+ Books</li></a>
            <ul  id="area" class="sitback">
            <a href><li>Fiction</li></a>
            <a href><li>Non-Fiction</li></a>
            <a href><li>Biography</li></a>
            </ul>
    <a href><li class="dept">+ Music</li></a>
            <ul  id="area" class="sitback">
            <a href><li>Digital Download</li></a>
            <a href><li>CDs</li></a>
            </ul>
    <a href><li class="dept">+ Experience Days</li></a>
            <ul  id="area" class="sitback">
            <a href><li>Hot Airballoon Ride</li></a>
            <a href><li>Track Days</li></a>
            </ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to achieve this using just CSS.

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0gueaga5/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item
        <ul>
            <li>SubItem</li>
            <li>SubItem</li>
            <li>SubItem</li>
            <li>SubItem</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li ul { display:none; }
li:hover ul { display:block; }
```

You hide the sub lists by default. And then set them to display when the parent list item is hovered over. You can make it "flashier" just by adding some more CSS. Look into *transitions*. Might be the flash you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you sir. Become a bit of a fiend for Jquery!

Comment: @greatbow Did you want a solution using jQuery? You achieve something similar with a basic select, `.click` & `.addClass` if so.

Comment: I did use Jquery in the Jay, Basic .click and .toggle. but I fell short on the drop-down (actually about a year ago) because I forget to wrong the nested list inside the </li> tag. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.